# Replication setup from higher version to lower version In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2017, transactional-replication

Is it possible to create Transactional Replication setup between 2017 Enterprise edition to 2005 Standard edition in MS SQL Server?

I heard that it is possible through scripts, is it right?

Comment: No, Publisher & Subscriber need to be within 2 versions. [MS SQL Replication Topology](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2016/08/12/suppported-sql-server-versions-in-replication-topology/)

Comment: we created transnational replication between 2017 to 2008R2 through scripts, it worked. but 2017 to 2005 i have no idea about this plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Publisher and Subscriber needs to be within 2 versions and Distributor should be higher than or equal to subscriber.  You can always configure with a Subscriber that is beyond 2 versions from Publisher through T-SQL scripts and it might work.  But it is not supported by Microsoft which means you are on your own if there is anything that blocks you.

As you called out, you should be able to configure replication between 2017 and 2008R2 but your 2008R2 server would miss all the improvements and updates we made to the internal stored procedures and metadata related to replication.  Though most of these changes should be backward compatible, some of these might not work as expected if your running them in unsupported configurations.